# ManagedFusion Rewriter 404 if trailing slash is missing?

Tags: mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, urlrewriter, managedfusion

I'm using ManagedFusion Rewriter as a reverse proxy. The configuration is fairly simple:

```
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*) http://www.example.com/api/$1 [P]
```

This will work pretty much for any URL. However, if the URL happens to *not* end on a trailing slash, it will fail.

A request like this will go fine perfectly: `GET api/report/`

```
2013-10-10T11:27:11 [Rewrite] Input: http://localhost:50070/api/report/
2013-10-10T11:27:11 [Rule 0] Input: /api/report/
2013-10-10T11:27:11 [Rule 0] Rule Pattern Matched
2013-10-10T11:27:11 [Rule 0] Output: http://www.example.com/api/report/
2013-10-10T11:27:11 [Rewrite] Proxy: http://www.example.com/api/report/
2013-10-10T11:27:11 **********************************************************************************
2013-10-10T11:27:11 [Proxy] Request: http://www.example.com/api/report/
2013-10-10T11:27:12 [Proxy] System.Net.HttpWebResponse
2013-10-10T11:27:12 [Proxy] Received '200 OK'
2013-10-10T11:27:12 [Proxy] Response: http://localhost:50070/api/report/
2013-10-10T11:27:12 [Proxy] Response is being buffered
2013-10-10T11:27:12 [Proxy] Responding '200 OK'
```

However, a request like this will return a 404 without even making the request on the proxied URL: `GET api/report/1`

```
2013-10-10T11:27:13 [Rewrite] Input: http://localhost:50070/api/report/1
2013-10-10T11:27:13 [Rule 0] Input: /api/report/1
2013-10-10T11:27:13 [Rule 0] Rule Pattern Matched
2013-10-10T11:27:13 [Rule 0] Output: http://www.example.com/api/report/1
2013-10-10T11:27:13 [Rewrite] Proxy: http://www.example.com/api/report/1
(the log file finishes right here)
```

This is my whole configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "log.txt"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*) http://www.example.com/api/$1 [P]
```

Any idea where may I be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** My workaround has been accepted as the solution in the Rewriter codebase, so I'll make this the accepted answer. Please, still provide feedback on possible approaches to it.

---

Found a workaround, but I don't think this is the actual solution, so I'll answer my own question but won't accept it as an answer. (Unless I change my mind later. Fate is a fickle mistress.)

I downloaded the source code of ManagedFusion.Rewriter (the latest one, apparently from GitHub, here: https://github.com/managedfusion/managedfusion-rewriter/releases) and integrated  it into my code base.

The class ManagedFusion.Rewriter.RewriterModule contains the following two methods:

```
private void context_PostResolveRequestCache(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = new HttpContextWrapper(((HttpApplication)sender).Context);

    // check to see if this is a proxy request
    if (context.Items.Contains(Manager.ProxyHandlerStorageName))
        context.RewritePath("~/RewriterProxy.axd");
}

private void context_PostMapRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = new HttpContextWrapper(((HttpApplication)sender).Context);

    // check to see if this is a proxy request
    if (context.Items.Contains(Manager.ProxyHandlerStorageName))
    {
        var proxy = context.Items[Manager.ProxyHandlerStorageName] as IHttpProxyHandler;

        context.RewritePath("~" + proxy.ResponseUrl.PathAndQuery);
        context.Handler = proxy;
    }
}
```

As the names imply, the first one is the handler of `PostResolveRequestCache`, while the second one is the handler for `PostMapRequestHandler`.

In both of my example requests, the `PostResolveRequestCache` handler was being invoked and working fine. However, for my failing request, `PostMapRequestHandler` was not being executed.

This made me think that maybe, for some reason, rewriting a specific resource that does not look like a directory to a resource that looks like a file through the usage of `RewritePath` was preventing the actual actual handler from being picked up, thus preventing the raising of `PostMapRequestHandler`.

As such, I upgraded the Rewriter project from .NET 3.5 to 4.5 and replaced these lines:

```
if (context.Items.Contains(Manager.ProxyHandlerStorageName))
    context.RewritePath("~/RewriterProxy.axd");
```

by these ones

```
if (context.Items.Contains(Manager.ProxyHandlerStorageName)) {
    var proxyHandler = context.Items[Manager.ProxyHandlerStorageName] as IHttpHandler;
    context.RemapHandler(proxyHandler);
}
```

With this, all the requests were being properly picked up by the handler and started working.

---

As a side note, I had some mistakes in the original rules, instead of

```
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*) http://www.example.com/api/$1 [P]
```

It should have been:

```
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*) http://www.example.com/api/$1 [QSA,P,NC]
```

- `QSA` to append the query string of the original request
- `NC` to match the regex case insensitive